# What is the name of this type of control and how can I implement one?

Tags: html

This is kind of out there, but I have no idea what this type of control is even called, so I can't look up any examples on how to implement it.

The control has two text areas side by side with arrows in between them. If a user selects a value or multiple values in one text area and then clicks the arrow that points to the other text area, the selected values will jump over to the other text area and be removed from the initial text area.

What is this called?

Comment: It's two text inputs with JavaScript behaviour attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one control. Usually it's implemented with 2 `<SELECT>` list boxes, the arrows have javascript functions attached to take the selected values in the one listbox and move them to the other. Ie. delete from one box and add to the other.

Take a look at this example I found via Google:
http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html

Comment: perfect, thanks JJ. This is exactly what I needed. I was trying to use text areas, the <select> list boxes are much better.